# Using getOrElseUpdate of TrieMap in Scala

Tags: scala, caching, concurrency

I am using the `getOrElseUpdate` method of `scala.collection.concurrent.TrieMap` (from `2.11.6`)

```
 // simplified for clarity

 val trie = new TrieMap[Int, Future[String]]

 def foo(): String = ... // a very long process

 val fut: Future[String] = trie.getOrElseUpdate(id, Future(foo()))
```

As I understand, if I invoke the `getOrElseUpdate` in multiple threads without any synchronization the `foo` is invoked just *once*.

Is it correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current implementation is that it will be invoked zero or one times.  It may be invoked without the result being inserted, however.  (This is standard behavior for CAS-based maps as opposed to ones that use synchronized.)